# What is the idiomatic way to add custom validation to Asp.Net Core controller parameters

Tags: api, asp.net-core

In my api, I have a controller that takes a string as an argument.

```
[HttpPost("{text}")]
public ActionResult PostSomething(string text){}
```

I want `text` to be one of three valid strings, lets say `"a", "b", "c"`. Is there a way to do this using some attribute or is the best way to simply have an if statment inside the controller?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can put it in a model and then use model validation or you can check text with a simple regex like [a|bc].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your simple scenario yes you can use attribute but it is better to follow Separation of Concerns principle and Single Responsibility Principle and extract all your validation logic into separate classes Validators  in this will help using such framework as [Fluent Validation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html)

or for huge amount of models to validate

[Fast Validator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastValidator)

Comment: I didn't know about Fluent Validation, thank you. Just so I know, what is the attribute I could use?

Comment: @EthanKharitonov as I wrote I do not recommend attributes, use Fluent Validation but you can use RegularExpression attribute! Check the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Why is Fluent Validation a better approach then the built in Asp.Net Core validation framework?

Comment: @EthanKharitonov First there is not built in Framework for validation! it is just few attributes!  I've explained with my answer. because of principles of OOD and built in it is not a framework and has a lot of limitations.

Comment: @EthanKharitonov if you want to validate huge amount of models I've created Fast Validation framework you can check it https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastValidator